# $\Sigma$ is maximally satisfiable $\iff$ there exists $M$ such that $\Sigma=\{\alpha \mid M\vDash \alpha\}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> A set of formulas $\Sigma$ is maximally satisfiable $\iff$ there exists $M$ such that $\Sigma=\{\alpha \mid M\vDash \alpha\}$.

I have easily proved that if $\Sigma$ is maximally satisfiable than $\Sigma$ can be written as $\Sigma=\{\alpha \mid M\vDash \alpha\}$ for a particular $M$, but I can't see how to prove the other direction. I started by assuming that $\Sigma \subset \Sigma'$, and then tried to show that if $\beta \in \Sigma'$ than $M\vDash \beta$, but I cound't get any further.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

Suppose not, i.e. that $Σ = \{ α ∣ M \vDash α \}$ fo some $M$, but $Σ$ is not maximal (clearly, $Σ$ is satisfiable: it has at least the model $M$).

If it is not maximal, there is a formula $\beta$ such that neither $\beta$ nor $\lnot \beta$ is in $Σ$.

But eitehr $M \vDash \beta$ or $M \vDash \lnot \beta$, contradicting the assumption of non-maximality.

Comment: Its more than just a hint, its as clear as a complete proof :-), thanks.